# How to display In Stock Product only in websites scope?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer, magento-1, product-list

I am having a problem in filtering and displaying in stock only product in websites scope.

I have 3 websites using one magento install.

I'm using **Display Out of Stock Products** setting in **System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory** and turning it into "**No**", but **this setting hide all out of stock product in all of my 3 websites**

I only want to make it works in 1 website only

Some say, I should use Observer, but I don't know how to use it

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, **Magento does not support different inventory on website level.**

Unfortunately, it is not easy to implement and involves a lot of modifications in the core of Magento.

Fortunately, there are some modules available, the most famous one being this one: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-location-inventory.html